# C program does not run on buildroot

Tags: buildroot, gtk3

I work for buildroot. My purpose work GUI on my buildroot with `Gtk3.0` and `Gstreamer1.0`. I use Olinuxino A13 so I wrote GUI code(Gtk3.0 hello world example) on this with codeblocks. I use Debian wheezy. I want transfer this code from Debian wheezy to buildroot. **I tried this:**

1. I transferred `/path_to_proectfile/bin/Debug/my_program`.`my_program` created by codeblocks. I wrote `./my_program` on terminal and code work. I transferred this file to my buildroot but `./my_program` does not work. It returns `No such file or directory` error.
2. I thought the problem might be compiling and tried compiled on terminal. I use `gcc -o my_program main.c 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0'` again work on Debian wheezy terminal. After I transferred to buildroot but result does not change. I tried different compile kind like `cc`,`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`etc. but every time `No such file or directory` error.

Finally when I don't use gtk library(Just use `printf Hello World`), I saw Hello world. When I add gtk library returns `No such file or directory` error. Have you any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to UNIX & Linux StackExchange. I am not much of a programmer, so unfortunately I can't help you with your issue. However, there could be others here who can. If you do not get a response here after some time, I suggest you consider posting on the StackOverflow.com Stack Exchange site as well? That community is dedicated to software professionals who may be better suited to assist you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to work on a Buildroot system, it has to be compiled with the cross-compiler provided by Buildroot. See slide 264 and following in https://bootlin.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-slides.pdf (i.e the "Application Development" section).